# iTerm2 doesn't recognize Ctrl-Left and Ctrl-Right

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal, iterm2

TLDR; I couldn't get the [Micro editor](https://github.com/zyedidia/micro) to recognize `Ctrl-Left` and `Ctrl-Right` key combinations. I thought I maybe have to add escape sequences to iTerm2 (screenshot). The `Keyboard Shortcut` input field (screenshot) only recognizes `Ctrl-Up` and `Ctrl-Down` but not the other two. What am I missing?

I'm using fish-shell if that's important.

[image: iTerm2 screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

From the description, it appears that you clicked on an existing definition.

To add a *new* definition,

- click on the **`+`** on the control where you see **Load Preset...*
- click in the input area at the top of the dialog where it says **Click to set**
- press <kbd>*Control*</kbd><kbd>*left-arrow*</kbd>
- pull-down the *Action* dialog, scroll near the end and select **Send text**
- click in the third field, which says **Enter text to send** (and apparently an *Escape* character isn't the way to start: try **`^[`** for the printable form, e.g., **`^[1;5D`**).